# How does 'manage.py test' work? (pdb problem)

Tags: django

I develop my django app on a mac with the dev server. When I run *manage.py test* I am able to break execution with pdb (as I can also when just running the site).

When I push the app to my linux production server (Ubuntu) running apache2/nginx pdb it no longer works on the site. It throws a BdbQuit Exception. I figured it would work when I ran *manage.py test*, but was surprised to find that the test just skipped over the pdb.set_trace() calls without stopping for them.

This seems to imply that *manage.py test* is running over the webserver, but that seems counter-intuitive, as my test code is pure python without any HTTP.

If *manage.py test* is hooking into the webserver is there a way for me to tell it to use the dev server?

I've tried installing ipdb, btw, and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've somehow diagnosed the problem wrongly. It simply doesn't make sense to say 'manage.py test is running over the webserver'. Your Django installation doesn't even know there's a webserver present, unless it's actually called by that webserver via WSGI - which obviously isn't the case when you're running tests via `manage.py`.

Are you sure your tests are being run correctly at all? Try putting a `self.assertTrue(False)` into the tests that have the call to `pdb`, to see if they fail as you expect - try it with the assertion alternately before and after the `pdb` and see what happens.

Comment: Right, I didn't think manage.py should be involving the webserver. It only occurred to me as the issue because the webserver is the primary difference in my production environment other than the OS, and pdb doesn't work for me on the production server because it is not set up to.